# How to open shapefile and display it on a Bing Map?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I want to display some shape files to a Bing Maps control for a Windows Store App. Is there any way to do this?

I've got the shape file, and have a working Bing Map control, but now I don't know how to open the shapefile in my app and display it on the map control. I've looked at a couple of packages including:

ArcGIS for .NET
nettopologysuite
osmsharp
ESRI Shapefile Reader (Catfood) from CodePlex

None of these look like what I need and don't have sample code that I can really judge from. I've tried ESRI Shapefile Reader (Catfood) and followed the steps at rbrundritt's blog but I can't figure out how to add it as a resource to my Windows Store App. I'm kind of stuck, any help would be appreciated.

The reason the ESRI Shapefile Reader package doesn't work is because it targets .NET 2.0 and won't work with Windows Store Apps (.NET 4.5). Can the Bing Map SDK accept shapefiles, or would I have to find a way to read the shapefile then feed it to a MapLayer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YEs. II built a portable class library that does this and works with Bing Maps in Windows Store, WP and WPF apps. You can find the project here: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/ Simply go to source code tab and press the download button. There is a sample Windows Store apps that shows how to load a local shapefile. You can also easily have the app download the shapefile from the web and do the same thing.